# Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'LocationRequest'

Tags: android, kotlin, location

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying to get the location in real time and show the coordinates in a toast. The trouble is that i can't continue with the code because it doesn't detect the LocationRequest () in the IniciartLocationRequest() function. Any ideas what it could be?

Twhe code below is the mainActivity (it remains to be finished)

```
package com.example.ubicacion

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.LocationRequest
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val permisoFineLocation = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    private val permisoCoarseLocation = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

    private val codigoSolicitudPermiso = 100

    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        iniciarLocationRequest()
    }

    private fun iniciarLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()


    }

    private fun validarPermisosUbicacion(): Boolean {
        val hayUbicacionPrecisa = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            permisoFineLocation
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        val hayUbicacionOrdinaria = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            permisoCoarseLocation
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        return hayUbicacionPrecisa && hayUbicacionOrdinaria
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun obtenerUbicacion() {
        /*fusedLocationClient?.lastLocation?.addOnSuccessListener(this,
            object : OnSuccessListener<Location> {
                override fun onSuccess(p0: Location?) {
                    if (p0 != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            p0.latitude.toString() + "-" + p0.longitude.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            })*/

        val callback = object : LocationCallback() {

            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(p0)
                for (ubicacion in p0.locations) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "a", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            callback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
    }

    private fun pedirPermisos() {
        val deboProveerContexto =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permisoFineLocation)

        if (deboProveerContexto) {
            //Mandar mensaje con expliacion adicinal
            solicitudPermiso()
        } else {
            solicitudPermiso()
        }
    }

    private fun solicitudPermiso() {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(permisoCoarseLocation, permisoFineLocation),
            codigoSolicitudPermiso
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        when (requestCode) {
            codigoSolicitudPermiso -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //obtener Ubicacion
                    obtenerUbicacion()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "No se dio permiso para acceder a la ubicacion",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        if (validarPermisosUbicacion()) {
            obtenerUbicacion()
        } else {
            pedirPermisos()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You get LocationRequest from the [LocationRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationRequest.Builder)

Comment: what other way to call the function I have?. Because anyway I always get a mistake